Run-time Error -2147417848(80010108) Value of object range failed
I have a sheet with many columns and I would like to trim columns and formatting them based on headers. Below VBA works great before but somehow I got

"Run-time Error -2147417848(80010108) Value of object range failed"

now.
Can anyone please help me to solve this error?
If you have any other suggestions how to make the same function with different ways is appreciated too!
Sub A_BigOrder_S()
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim acell As Range, nf, v

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ChDrive "C:\"
    
    strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Spreadsheet to Open")
    Set src = ActiveSheet
  
    For Each acell In src.Range("A1:JH1").Cells
        nf = "" 'clear numberformat
        v = UCase(Trim(acell.Value))   'get the column header
        Select Case True
            Case v Like "ITEM ID*"
                nf = "@"
                src.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                TrimSpaces acell.Offset(0)
            Case v Like "GMC*"
                nf = "@"
                src.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                TrimSpaces acell.Offset(0)
            Case v Like "PL*"
                nf = "@"
                src.Columns(acell.Column).ColumnWidth = 4
                TrimSpaces acell.Offset(0)
            Case v Like "OEM*"
                nf = "@"
                src.Columns(acell.Column).ColumnWidth = 4
                TrimSpaces acell.Offset(0)
            Case v Like "*DATE": nf = "mm/dd/yy"
            Case v Like "*PRICE*"
                nf = "0.00"
                src.Columns(acell.Column).ColumnWidth = 7.2
                TrimSpaces acell.Offset(0)
            Case v Like "*COST*"
                nf = "0.00"
                src.Columns(acell.Column).ColumnWidth = 7.2
                TrimSpaces acell.Offset(0)
            Case v Like "*Marg*"
                nf = "0.00"
                src.Columns(acell.Column).ColumnWidth = 7.2
                TrimSpaces acell.Offset(0)
            Case v Like "*PART*"
                nf = "@"
                src.Columns(acell.Column).ColumnWidth = 8.3
                TrimSpaces acell.Offset(0)
            Case v Like "VEN*"
                nf = "@"
                src.Columns(acell.Column).ColumnWidth = 4
                TrimSpaces acell.Offset(0)
           Case v Like "*CUFT*"
                nf = "0.00"
                src.Columns(acell.Column).ColumnWidth = 7.2
        End Select
        
        'any number format to apply?
        If Len(nf) > 0 Then src.Columns(acell.Column).NumberFormat = nf
    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
DoEvents
End Sub

'Trim spaces from a column of data, starting at cell `B`
Function TrimSpaces(B As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In B.Parent.Range(B, B.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, B.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
        If cell = "" Then
           cell.ClearContents
        ElseIf cell = 0 Then
               cell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next cell
End Function



On which row do you get the error?

You need to remove two End Function lines between Function TrimSpaces(B As Range) and Dim cell As Range frist.

Sorry, my code doesn't have that line. Somehow pasted it wrong. and I got the error at this line cell.ClearContents (the 2nd one)

Any event handlers on that worksheet?

@Lavinci Applying the trim function to each individual cell is time-consuming and will also be memory-intensive, you might want to evaluate the used range as a whole. btw why do you want to clear contents of empty cells? It might be also more resource-saving to autofit only the used range instead of an entire column. You find answers by your own to all of these hints at SO :-;

Your "Cell.ClearContents" is changing the range you're iterating over if it's the last cell in the range.  The range in the "In" portion of your loop get evaluated for each iteration, so if you change the range in the "In" the by clearing a cell (changing the results of the xlUp, you can end up with a cell outside of the range you're evaluating.

@FrankBall - I thought the In part of For Each only gets evaluated once, before the iteration begins, not on every iteration?

@Tim Williams - Think about what would happen if you changed the collection during processing.  Take a case where you're using a Loop to clean up duplicate entries.  You find an entry, and then remove all the duplicates.  If your "In" only gets evaluated at the beginning, your entire loop is now invalid because there are missing elements.  Loop have to re-evaluate with each iteration.

@FrankBall - it doesn't though, and there are many questions here where "loop backwards though the collection if you're deleting items in the loop" is the answer, because the In clause only gets evaluated at the start of the loop.

@TimWilliams - Looping backwards works because the In gets re-evaluated.  If you remove an element from a collection and the loop tried to access that element, it will fail because there's no element to access.  That's how the forward loop fails, an element gets removed, but VBA isn't smart enough to keep the iteration in sync with the modified collection, so the iteration ends up out of sync with the collection.  In Excel this is highly visible when deleting rows, but it happens with any collection.

@FrankBall - you wrote "The range in the "In" portion of your loop get evaluated for each iteration" and I was only disagreeing with that statement. It does not get re-evaluated on each iteration, and it's quite straightforward to show that. Assuming you were referring to this line: For Each cell In B.Parent.Range(B, B.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, B.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells Looping backwards works because you use a Long/Integer counter and the collection creation is either moved into the loop and so gets re-executed for each iteration, or ...

...because you're working backwards you never refer "past" an already-deleted member of that collection.

@TimWilliams - Backwards looping is done because of the evaluation done on each iteration.  Once a collection is modified, VBA doesn't keep the iteration in sync with the new collection. You can start with a collection of 10 elements, remove one and the iterator will still execute 10 times.  VBA is dumb this way because it knows the number of elements originally but doesn't adjust to the change.  That's why backwards looping is used.   But if you resize the collection using the XLEndUp, you end up with a new collection that the iterator does recognize because the SIZE of the collection changed

The number of elements and the size aren't the same thing.  They are 2 different properties of a collection and VBA isn't smart enough to recognize that they should be in sync.  So you can delete an element the size doesn't change, but the number of elements does change (like I said, it's dumb that way).  The iterator uses the size of the collection, not the number of elements.  When you use XLEndUp that defines the size of the collection and every time the iterator processes it checks the size to determine it's position within the loop.

" When you use XLEndUp that defines the size of the collection and every time the iterator processes it checks the size to determine it's position within the loop." Have you tested that though?

To be clear I do not believe I understand the internals or exactly how a For Each loop works, but it's always been my understanding that the expression following the In only gets evaluated once, and in my testing that appears to be the case.

I see a few problems that might help
1. please use Option Explicit and declare all variables, and include type definitions
So:
    Option Explicit

    Sub A_BigOrder_S()
        Dim src As Worksheet
        Dim acell As Range, nf As String, v As String
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ChDrive "C:\"
        
        Dim strFileToOpen As String

2. this code gets a file name, but doesn't open the file:
    strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Spreadsheet to Open")
    Set src = ActiveSheet

strFileToOpen gets set with the selected file name
so scr may not be the worksheet that you think!
I suggest something like this:
Sub OpenFileDialog()
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet

    filePath = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="Excel and CSV Files (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.csv),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.csv", _
        Title:="Select an Excel or CSV File")

    If filePath <> "" Then
        ' Open the selected file in a new workbook
        Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
       
        Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        wsNew.name = wsImportSheetname
        
        ' Copy data from the opened workbook to the new worksheet
        wbTarget.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy wsNew.Range("A1")

        ' Close the opened workbook
        wbTarget.Close False

        Set wbTarget = Nothing
        Set wsNew = Nothing
    End If
    
End Sub

3. I'm not sure you need the .Offset(0) part. maybe pass the column number that you want to trim, instead of a range B. You defined a Function, but it should be a Sub, something like:
    Sub TrimSpacesFromColumn(ws As Worksheet, columnNumber As Long)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    
    ' Find the last row with data in the specified column
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the specified column
    For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, columnNumber), ws.Cells(lastRow, columnNumber))
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            ' Trim spaces from the cell's value
            cell.Value = Application.Trim(cell.Value)
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

and then you could call it like:
TrimSpaces src, acell.Column

Please note that I haven't tested this code... just some ideas I hoped would help
